# Exclude all other active IDs in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, redirect, conditional-statements

I am writing a simple function with an `if` statement redirecting the user based on their choices. Basically, the user sees a couple of options (A, B, C, etc). and the user is redirect to one URL when say A and B are selected, and to another URL when say A and C are selected.

So far, this works, using the following code:

```
function redirect() {
    if (((document.getElementById('A').classList.contains('active')) == true) && ((document.getElementById('B').classList.contains('active')) == true)) {
        window.location = "https://www.example.com";
    };
};
```

My problem is that I also want to be able to exclude all other possibilities, meaning that I want to add a clause redirecting the user if A and B are selected, but none of the other options. Is there a way to do this without explicitly listing all other options as `('active')) == false`?

Thank you again, and sorry if this question reflects my elementary knowledge of coding.

Comment: You need to check explicitely

Comment: Try something with the `map`, `every` and `some` [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods.

Comment: why not just `var a = (document.getElementById('A').classList.contains('active'))` and similar for `b` and `c`. Then you check `if (a && b)` etc

Answer (score 0):

One could store all the *is active* values:

```
const ids = ["A","B","C","D","E"],state = {};
for(const id of ids)
   state[id] = document.getElementById(id).classList.contains('active');
```

And then:

```
if( state.A && state.B)
```

Comment: And how would this _exclude_ all other IDs? Why not just use `Array#map` or `Array#reduce`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of all the elements having the `active` class and loop through them.

```
// Get a list of all elements having the "active" class
var activeElements = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
var redirect = true; 

// Loop through all the elements having the active class
// and set redirect to false if one of them doesn't have one of the following ID: 'A' or 'B'
for (var i =0; i<activeElements.length;i++) {
    if(activeElements[i].id != 'A' && activeElements[i].id != 'B') {
        redirect = false;
    }
} 

//If the redirect variable is still true
if(redirect){
    redirect();
}
```

In this case, your `redirect()` function would use the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

```
// url has a default value. So you can call the function these ways:
// redirect();   --> redirects to https://example.com
// redirect("https://stackoverflow.com"); --> redirects to StackOverflow.
function redirect(url = 'https://example.com') {
        window.location = url;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
var A = (document.getElementById('A').classList.contains('active')) == true)?arr.push('A'):false;
var B = (document.getElementById('B').classList.contains('active')) == true)?arr.push('B'):false;
var C = (document.getElementById('C').classList.contains('active')) == true)?arr.push('C'):false;

if(arr.includes('A') && arr.includes('B') && arr.length ==2){

}
```

Comment: I think you meant [`arr.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (with an s)

Comment: Why not just `var arr = ["A", "B", "C"].filter(id => document.getElementById(id).classList.contains("active"));` or `var arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".active")).map(elem => elem.id)`? The `&&` chain can also be replaced by `Array#every`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please explain what the ?arr.push method does and why it is set as false?

Comment: @Andre `?:` is the ternary operator.

Comment: Seems to work, both Sugumar's answer, and Xufox's alternative
Thank you again!

Comment: @Xufox you are an expert bro